# what causes a docker volume to be populated?

Tags: docker

I am running the following command:

`docker run --name wiki --link wiki-mdb:mysql -p 9081:80 -v /var/data/wikimedia/apache2:/etc/apache2 -v /var/data/wikimedia/wiki:/var/www/html -d synctree/mediawiki`

and the container dies because apache2 cant find its config file in /etc/apach2 ...

ok, so I run the command again without the apache2 volume as:

`docker run --name wiki --link wiki-mdb:mysql -p 9081:80 -v /var/data/wikimedia/wiki:/var/www/html -d synctree/mediawiki`

and not only does it work ... but /var/data/wikimedia/wiki which started out as empty is populated with all the php files needed.

so what is the difference?  Why are some volumes populated with content from container while other volumes will prefer to mount the blank folder over top of a containers internal configuration?

I ended up solving my issue by running `sudo docker cp 9f9ba217a2ec:/etc/apache2 ./` to generate a default apache2 folder ... however it seems like there should be some rhyme or reason to why content is generated in the volume or not.

I thought it might have something to do with the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/synctree/mediawiki/~/dockerfile/), but it does not have any specific reference to either path.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `-v /var/data/wikimedia/apache2:/etc/apache2` links your local `/var/data/wikimedia/apache2` with `/etc/apache2` within the container. This masks the container folder created at the build time. Because `/etc/apache2` is where apache is looking for its configuration, linking `/var/data/wikimedia/apache2` without configuration into `/etc/apache2` results in server finding no configuration and failing to start.

Leaving this volume out *does not* mask the already present `/etc/apache2` folder within the container created at the build time, thus keeping configuration files placed by there the `Dockerfile` script at the build time intact. The server finds a suitable configuration and starts as expected.

I am not a pro in php and in particular at which point which files are generated if at all, but I suspect that as the server starts normally php files are being populated into `/var/www/html` in the container (apparently). Because the latter is just a link to your local `/var/data/wikimedia/wiki` you can also see those files on your host system.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your answer with `/etc/apache2` masking the present content ... however, I am not sure the second part of your answer is correct ... it too starts as a blank folder and should mask existing content.  The web server itself is not generating the .php content.  What might be happening is that the apache2 gets masked because it is a sub layer of the container image and only the content generated in the top most image populates over the volume ... but I cant find documentation for this theory.