# docker volume, configuration files aren't generated

Tags: apache, docker, settings, volume

Same kind of issue than : [what causes a docker volume to be populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132411/what-causes-a-docker-volume-to-be-populated)

I'm trying to share configuration file of apache in /etc/apache2 with my host, and file aren't generated automatically within the shared folder.

As minimal example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt update

#Install apache
RUN apt install -y apache2 apache2-dev

ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: apache-server
        volumes:
            - ./log/:/var/log/apache2
            - ./config:/etc/apache2/ #remove it will let log generating files
        image: httpd-perso2
        build: .
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

With this configuration, nor `./config` nor `./log` will be filled with files/folders generated by the container, even if log files should have some error (getting `apache-server | The Apache error log may have more information.`)

If I remove the `./config` volume, apache log files will be generated properly. Any clue for which reason this can append ? How can I share apache config file ?
Having the same issue with django settings file, seem to be related to config file generated by an application.

**What I tried :**
- using `VOLUME` in Dockerfile
- running `docker-compose` as root or chmod 777 on folders
- Creating file within the container to those directory to see if they are created on the host (and they did)
- On host, creating shared folder chown by the user (chown by root if they are automatically generated)
- Trying with `docker run`, having exactly the same issue.

**For specs:**
- Docker version 19.03.5
- using a VPS with debian buster
- docker-compose version 1.25.3

Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Copying image content to newly created volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) only works with... volumes, not with bind mounts (i.e. path mounted from you host).

Comment: Ok, I see, the content of the host folder is copied to the container, so it delete all files which was originally in the image, and created by all `Dockerfile` commands.

Comment: Bind mount does not copy, it mounts: they are exactly the same files. You would get the exact same result by mounting a disk on your linux system on a path that already has content: you would see the content of the new disk.

Comment: So it allow only container to add content at runtime to interact with the host.

For exemple with configuration data, it's not possible to retrieve them from the image, it's necessary the host who provide them ?

Comment: Back to my first comment: copying image at a specific path to the volume being on the same path only works with docker volumes, not with bind mounts. Meanwhile... you can easily put your config files in `/what/ever/template_config` and copy them on `/etc/my_configs` when the container starts if that dir is empty. If you bind mount `/etc/my_configs`, you will get your files on the host. The `mysql` image for example will init a db system in `/var/lib/mysql` on start if it is empty. If you bind mount an empty dir, you will get a fresh db.